# Elastic Search Aggregation Interval

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

While aggregating in elastic-search I am unable to set interval multiple of the month. And it is quite obvious it works well with **1M** but not more. What I feel is all intervals supported are good but not sufficient. During date histogram creation I need an interval multiple of months (Multiplier is heavily differing). Is there any way to aggregate not using day and week multiple. I don't think months can be generalized in terms of **week** and **day** accurately.

Comment: Fractional/Multiple time expressions are only available for seconds, minutes, hours, days and weeks, but not month simply because not every month contains the same number of days.

Comment: There is the same issue for years. See also https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8939

Comment: What bad I faced with use of weeks here is, the date received after query execution have no exact difference of required no. of months,i.e date upon which aggregation carried out looks not much good. Apparently, months(particular one) are of fixed number of days.